# Не работает каскадное удаление JPA(Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Грубо говоря, есть 2 сущности.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "university_group")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
       orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    // getters, setters, constructor, equals+hashcode ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Group group;

    // getters, setters, constructor, equals+hashcode ...
}
```

Во время удаления группы с помощью `em.remove(group)` выбрасывается

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
...
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ОШИБКА: UPDATE или DELETE в таблице "university_group" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "fk_20su8ubuwt33je1a3ygal7wd6" таблицы "student"
  Подробности: На ключ (id)=(7630) всё ещё есть ссылки в таблице "student".
```

Похоже, хибернейт и не хочет сначала удалять студентов средствами Persistence Provider. Удалять, используя средства каскадирования БД не хочу, т.к. почему Persistence Provider этого не делает.

Конфигурировал EntityManager Spring'ом.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:db.properties"})
public class PersistenceContext {

    private static final String BASE_MODEL_SCAN_PACKAGE = "com.chiefhelpsystem.model";

    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String dbClassName;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String dbUserName;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setMaxIdle(20);
        ds.setMinIdle(0);
        ds.setMaxActive(20);

        ds.setDriverClassName(dbClassName);
        ds.setUrl(dbUrl);
        ds.setUsername(dbUserName);
        ds.setPassword(dbPassword);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        emFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emFactory.setPackagesToScan(BASE_MODEL_SCAN_PACKAGE);
        emFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProps());
        emFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        return emFactory;
    }

    private Properties jpaProps() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Hibernate 4.3.11, Spring 4.3.2

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком, что фактически находится в Group.students на момент удаления (ну или добавьте вывод списка в консоль, если с отладкой проблемы). Если там нет списка студентов или в нём отсутствует (id)=(7630), то в первую очередь надо разбираться с причинами рассинхронизации данных в Java-сущностях с данными в БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с неправильной реализацией hashcode(); После его удаления, в стектрейсе всё-таки появился лог с "un-managed delete" -
дальше уже всё сводилось к решению этой проблемы.